# Цвета линий в Matplolib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть график:

```
plt.xlabel('Length')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.axis([length_h[0], length_h[-1], time_tau[0], time_tau[-1]])
plt.plot(An[-1], U[-1])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

но цвета линий всегда одинаковые, если я разделяю `plt.plot(An[-1], U[-1])` на два, то вид графика меняется.
Как можно сделать два разных цвета для двух линий в одном `plt.plot()`
Выходит вот такой график
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно чтобы эти линии были разных цветов

Если я их делю вот так:

```
plt.xlabel('Length')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.axis([length_h[0], length_h[-1], time_tau[0], time_tau[-1]])
plt.plot(An[-1], 'r')
plt.plot(U[-1], 'b')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

То график выглядеть начинает по-другому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
U
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
An
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А, кажется понятно. У вас что вообще в `An[-1], U[-1]`, может двумерные массивы?

Comment: Вообще они двумерные, но если я беру -1 индекс, он же просто мне вернет одномерный список. Не думаю что в этом проблема.

Comment: Хм. Почему тогда две линии получается? А, наверное у вас данные "закольцованы". Был бы двумерный массив, тогда бы два разных цвета рисовались. Покажите ваши данные уже!

Comment: Да, хотелось бы глянуть исходные данные для графиков

Comment: Две линии получается потому что я подаю два списка в plot

Comment: @uppjke Нет! Первый список это x-ы, второй это y-ки! Покажите, что у вас в данных! Вполне возможно, что вы вообще рисуете не то, что нужно. Покажите данные и объясните - что вы вообще хотите нарисовать собственно.

Comment: Добавил данные.

Comment: А напечатать мне нужно линии для -1 списка у двух разных массивов

Comment: Ну, что я и говорил - у вас в первом списке значения сначала увеличиваются, а потом уменьшаются. Смотрите тот мой ответ, который про "закольцованные" данные, он вам подойдёт. И впредь прикладывайте данные в текстовом виде, как и код. Никто не будет набивать данные со скриншотов, чтобы воспроизвести у себя вашу проблему.

Comment: почему данные в виде скриншота? что вас остановила после постинга кода в текстовом виде также привести данные?

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, я понял. У вас данные "закольцованы". Тогда можно их так разделить попробовать:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 4
x = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
y = [0, 1.25, 2, 0.75, 0]
x_max_ind = max(enumerate(x_arr), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
plt.plot(x[:x_max_ind+1], y[:x_max_ind+1])
plt.plot(x[x_max_ind:], y[x_max_ind:])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как это сделать "из коробки", но наколхозить вручную можно легко по отдельным отрезкам:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 4
x_arr = range(n)
y_arr = [i**2 for i in range(n)]
c_arr = ['red','green','blue']
for i in range(n-1):
    x = x_arr[i:i+2]
    y = y_arr[i:i+2]
    c = c_arr[i]
    plt.plot(x, y, color=c)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну у Вас получается что plt.plot() делится на несколько, а мне нужно чтобы это было в одном. Дополнил вопрос.